How to add decimal places in to my oracle SQL query result
I have the following query
select oc.card_number,
       case opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' then '05-PURCHASE' 
       when 'OPTP0020' then '06-CREDIT VOUCHER' 
       else 'other' end as Transaction_Type,
       opt.oper_date as "TRANSACTION_DATE", 
       op.account_number, 
       case vf.sttl_currency
       when '840' then 'USD'
       end as "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY", 
       case opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' then  -vf.sttl_amount
       else  vf.sttl_amount
       end as "SOURCE_AMOUNT",
       op.auth_code, 
       opt.mcc, 
       opt.terminal_number as "TERMINAL_ID", 
       vf.pos_terminal_cap, 
       vf.pos_entry_mode,
       opt.part_key as "CAPTURE_DATE", 
       opt.oper_amount as "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT",
       opt.oper_currency as "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY",
       opt.merchant_name,
       COALESCE(cc.visa_country_code,opt.merchant_country) merchant_country,
       opt.clearing_sequence_num, 
       opt.clearing_sequence_count, 
       opt.oper_type
FROM   opr_operation opt 
       INNER JOIN opr_participant op
       ON op.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN opr_card oc
       ON oc.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN vis_fin_message vf
       ON     opt.id = vf.id
       INNER JOIN  com_country cc
       ON cc.code= opt.merchant_country 
          AND op.card_id = vf.card_id
WHERE  opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1
AND    opt.part_key >= DATE '2024-03-01'
AND    opt.msg_type IN ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC')
AND    op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS'

Which gives the following output:
"CARD_NUMBER"   "TRANSACTION_TYPE"  "TRANSACTION_DATE"  "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT" "AUTH_CODE" "MCC"   "TERMINAL_ID"   "POS_TERMINAL_CAP"  "POS_ENTRY_MODE"    "CAPTURE_DATE"  "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT"    "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY"  "MERCHANT_NAME" "MERCHANT_COUNTRY"  "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_NUM" "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_COUNT"   "OPER_TYPE"
"1234567891234567"  "05-PURCHASE"   25-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   -2020   "718515"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    27-MAR-24   2020    "060"   "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"

But, it is possible to get column F - 'SOURCE_AMOUNT' to return the value with 2 decimal places?
So in the example above, -2020 should be displayed as -20.20
I did try to do to_char as below but it is not correct and doesnt work
 case opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' then to_char (coalesce (-vf.sttl_amount,0)999999.99)
       else  vf.sttl_amount
       end as "SOURCE_AMOUNT",

Any help would be great please.

What type is the sttl_amount? Is it NUMBER or (VAR)CHAR?

Hi @TheNomad is it NUMBER (22,4) but I don't believe there would ever be more than 2 digits after the decimal point so I don't quite understand that.

Ah, it's for some currencies that have special cases. For example, the JPY have no decimals and the CLF has 4 decimal places. So most likely, the precision is 4 because it's meant to cover any situation, even though you might internally only use 2. For audit and investigations, best practice is to save what you actually receive (in your theoretical case, 4 decimal digits IF you'd work with CLF).

Are you 100% sure your requirement is correct? I mean that 2020 should be 20.20? And that it applies to every record of every currency and is not just some crazy exception somewhere depending on some other marker (like negative values depending on OPTP0000)?

Ah ok thanks @TheNomad that makes sense. Playing around with the different formats, I sill cant get the decimal point to show in the right place. I keep getting the decimal point after the amount. But I need -2020 to be displayed as -20.20 but I'm getting all sorts of weird results as I keep moving the 'G' around. Any ideas? Looking at the documentation using 99G999D99 should give me what I need but it still ends up displaying as -2,020.00 which is wrong

Yes, these are all converted currencies in the end so all is USD. I can leave it as 2020 knowing that is $$cc but if there is a way to make it $$.cc that would look better for me

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@headspace - 99G999D99 will only show non-zero values after the decimal point, as the docs say. 99G999D00 will always show two digits after it even if they are zero; and 99G990D00 will also always show a zero before decimal, for values less than 1. Which is what Littlefoot showed - not sure why you changed those back to 9s. If you're storing values in cents/pence/whatever then you'd need to divide by 100 - but again are you sure that's correct?

Hi @AlexPoole I only tried playing around with the values as my output wasn't correct. If I do 99G999D00 the output I get is -2,020.00. So on that basis, I would then need to divide by 100 as you have mentioned above but I'm not clear on how to do this.

Apply TO_CHAR with appropriate format model to the whole CASE expression, e.g.
   TO_CHAR (
      CASE opt.oper_type
         WHEN 'OPTP0000' THEN COALESCE (-vf.sttl_amount, 0)
         ELSE vf.sttl_amount
      END,
      '999G990D00') AS SOURCE_AMOUNT

This will apply thousands separator and decimal point character to that value. Check documentation for other possibilities.

Although not related to your question: try not to use double quotes in Oracle; in vast majority of cases they aren't needed. As you used them as column/expression aliases and all of them are in capital letters with underline character between words, there's no difference among source_amount, SOURCE_AMOUNT, "SOURCE_AMOUNT" and similar.

Thanks @littlefoot and noted on the double quotes.

select oc.card_number,
       case opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' then '05-PURCHASE' 
       when 'OPTP0020' then '06-CREDIT VOUCHER' 
       else 'other' end as Transaction_Type,
       opt.oper_date as TRANSACTION_DATE, 
       op.account_number, 
       case vf.sttl_currency
       when '840' then 'USD'
       end as "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY", 
   TO_CHAR (
      CASE opt.oper_type
         WHEN 'OPTP0000' THEN COALESCE (-vf.sttl_amount /100, 0)
         ELSE vf.sttl_amount /100
      END,
      '99G999D00') AS SOURCE_AMOUNT,
       op.auth_code, 
       opt.mcc, 
       opt.terminal_number as TERMINAL_ID, 
       vf.pos_terminal_cap, 
       vf.pos_entry_mode,
       opt.part_key as CAPTURE_DATE, 
       TO_CHAR (
       CASE opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' THEN COALESCE (-vf.oper_amount /100, 0)
       ELSE vf.oper_amount /100
       END,
       '99G999D00') as TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,
       COALESCE(ccu.name,opt.oper_currency) TRANSACTION_CURRENCY,
       opt.merchant_name,
       COALESCE(cc.visa_country_code,opt.merchant_country) merchant_country,
       opt.clearing_sequence_num, 
       opt.clearing_sequence_count, 
       opt.oper_type
FROM   opr_operation opt 
       INNER JOIN opr_participant op
       ON op.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN opr_card oc
       ON oc.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN vis_fin_message vf
       ON     opt.id = vf.id
       INNER JOIN  com_country cc
       ON cc.code= opt.merchant_country 
          AND op.card_id = vf.card_id
       INNER JOIN  com_currency ccu
       ON ccu.code= opt.oper_currency 
          AND op.card_id = vf.card_id   
WHERE  opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1
AND    opt.part_key >= DATE '2024-03-01'
AND    opt.msg_type IN ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC')
AND    op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS'

OK, this works to give me the output on top of @Littlefoot answer too. Thanks
